# Must there always be a normal element with non-discrete spectrum in an infinite-dimensional C*-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Suppose that $A$ is an infinite-dimensional $C^*$-algebra. Is it true that there must be a normal element with non-discrete spectrum? If that is not true must there at least be a normal element with infinite spectrum?

Edit: To clarify, by discrete spectrum I mean that the spectrum consists only of isolated points. Since the spectrum is closed this is the same as saying that it has no accumulation points.

I have also found, via MathOverflow, the following [article](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=3083484) which claims that there if $A$ is semi-simple there exists a self-adjoint element in $A$ with infinite spectrum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is true.  As mentioned in the article you linked to in the Remark on page 4, every infinite dimensional C*-algebra contains a self-adjoint element with infinite spectrum.  (In context it helps to know that every C*-algebra is semi-simple.)  A reference is given to Ogasawara's "Finite dimensionality of certain Banach algebras," which doesn't appear to be readily available online.  (I do not have a more easily accessible reference or proof off hand.)  Note that the only compact discrete subsets of $\mathbb C$ are the finite subsets, so your two questions are the same.

Comment: Without normality this seems to be due to Irving Kaplansky, *[Ring isomorphisms of Banach algebras](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1954-036-5)*, Canad. J. Math. **6** (1954), 374-381, Lemma 7 on page 376. See also Alan W. Tullo, *[Conditions on Banach algebras which imply finite dimensionality](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0013091500015698)*, 
Proceedings of the Edinburgh Mathematical Society (Series 2) (1976), **20**, 1-5, lemma on page 4. The remark after the lemma states that Ogasawara's result follows from that.

Comment: Ah, thank you. $    $

Answer (score 2):

The operators on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space of the form $\alpha I + K$ where $K$ is a compact operator form an infinite-dimensional $C^*$-algebra in which every element has discrete spectrum.

Comment: Maybe I misspoke but by discrete spectrum I meant that all points in the spectrum are isolated. That is not true for a general compact operator.