# $\dim$ $C(X,\mathbb{R})<\infty$ we need to show $|X|<\infty$,

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

$X$ be a compact Hausdorff space such that $\dim$ $C(X,\mathbb{R})<\infty$  we need to show $|X|<\infty$, I must say I have no idea how to prove this result. please help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show that you can always extend a function defined on a finite set of points on $X$ to a continuous function on all of $X$?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/250325/49437 for a generalization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $N$ be the dimension of $C(X,\Bbb R)$. Assume that there are $N+1$ distinct points $x_1,\dots,x_{N+1}$ in $X$. As $X$ is *compact* and Hausdorff it is normal, hence by the Urysohn lemma, we can find for each $j$ a continuous function $g_j\colon X\to\Bbb R$ such that $g_j(x_k)=0$ when $k\neq j$ and $g_j(x_j)=1$.

The family $\{g_j,1\leqslant j\leqslant N+1\}$ is necessarily linearly dependent, so we can assume that $g_{N+1}=\sum_{j=1}^Ng_j$. Evaluating this equality at $x_{N+1}$ yields a contradiction.

This proves that $\dim C(X,\Bbb R)=\operatorname{card}(X)$.

The result is not necessarily true when $X$ is not assumed to be Hausdorff. For example, take $X$ an infinite set with the topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$. The only continuous functions are constant ones.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth pointing out where we used the compactness assumption...

Comment: @ZhenLin: Even I can't see where compactness is used.

Comment: You need some assumption on $X$ to apply Urysohn's lemma.

Comment: You are right. This is indeed where compactness is used (I should have done this edit one year ago...).