# $C([0,1])$ is not weakly sequentially complete.

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm studying Functional Analysis by myself.
For a counterexample of every Banach space is not weakly sequentially complete, I was suggested to check $C([0,1])$ is not weakly sequentially complete. For this, let $f_n(t)=1-nt$ if $0\leq t\leq \frac{1}{n}$ and $f_n(t)=0$ if $\frac{1}{n}\leq t \leq 1$.
But I do not know how to use monotone convergence theorem to show $\{f_n\}$ is weakly Cauchy and also why it is not weakly sequentially complete. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x^*\in C([0,1])^*$ be any continuous functional. Then there is a finite measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$, such that 
$$ \int_{[0,1]} f\, d\mu = x^*(f), \qquad f \in C[0,1] $$
Now, by dominated convergence, we have
$$ \int_{[0,1]} (f_n - f_m) \, d\mu \to 0 ,\qquad n,m \to \infty $$
Edit: By looking at $\mu = \delta_x$, $x \in [0,1]$, show that $(f_n)$ cannot converge weakly to a continuous function.

Comment: I thought $f_n \rightharpoonup 0$ too for a moment, but consider $\delta_0 \in C([0,1])^\ast$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Fact 1. Note that $c_0$ is not weakly sequentially complete. Just consider sequence $\left(\sum_{k=1}^n e_k\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Fact 2. [Any $C(K)$ for infinite Hausdorff compact $K$ contains a copy of $c_0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/250524/19538).

Fact 3. The property of being weakly sequentially complete is preserved by subspaces. 
Indeed, let $Y$ be a closed subspace of weakly sequentially complete space $X$. Consider weakly Cauchy sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $Y$, then obviously it is weakly Cauchy in $X$. Since $X$ is weakly sequentially complete then $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ weakly converges to some $x\in X$. Thus $x$ lies in the weak closure of $Y$. Since $Y$ is closed and convex, then by [Mazur's theorem](http://books.google.ru/books?id=WRc3ciSmsMMC&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=Mazur%20theorem%20weak%20closure&source=bl&ots=6sAwIKVITm&sig=qxlR5JBMx6t5_04CXVpzgXx1WfI&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=VUw6VOj3BqPiywOj44H4Cg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Mazur%20theorem%20weak%20closure&f=false) weak closure coincides with $Y$. Thus weak limit of $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ $\in Y$, and $Y$ is weakly sequentially complete.

Conclusion. Any $C(K)$ is not weakly sequentially complete.

It is standard trick to show that a Banach space contains a copy of $c_0$ and then conclude that this space is not weakly sequentially complete.

Comment: I think C(K) is a subspace of $L^\infty(K)$ and $L^\infty(K)$ is weakly sequentially complete while C(K) is not. it's a counter example for fact3. isn't it?

Comment: Why is $L_\infty(K)$ is weakly sequentially complete? I think it is not.

Comment: Oh, In the old version of Conway's Functional Analysis it's an exercise. but checking in new version, I found $L^\infty$ is weak* sequentially complete.

Answer (score 1):

The monotone convergence theorem also works for *decreasing* sequences $\{f_n\}$ provided $f_1\in L^1$ (cf. Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, exercises to chap.1), which is the case in your problem. For any regular Borel measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$, $\int_0^1 f_n d\mu \to \mu(\{0\})$, so the sequence is weakly convergent and hence weakly Cauchy. Here we are using the basic property of finite measures that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu([0,1/n])= \mu(\cap_{n=1}^\infty[0,1/n])$. Check that $f_n$ converges weakly to the (discontinuous) characteristic function $\chi_{\{0\}}$.