# Subspace of a weakly sequentially complete is weakly sequentially complete

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, cauchy-sequences

A Banach space $X$ is called weakly sequentially complete if all weakly Cauchy sequences are weakly convergent.

Question: If $Y$ is a subspace of a Banach space $X$, must $Y$ be weakly sequentially complete?

My guess is yes, but I don't know how to prove it.

Any hint is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes. See Norbert's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866650/c0-1-is-not-weakly-sequentially-complete).

Comment: To transport a quick summary: subspaces are strongly closed and convex, thus weakly closed. It is a general fact that a sequentially closed subset of a sequentially complete space is sequentially complete, in whatever topology.