# The space of bounded continuous function $C_b(X)$ is reflexive iff $X$ is finite

Tags: metric-spaces, dual-spaces, reflexive-space

This question comes from [Space of bounded functions is reflexive if the domain is finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250325/space-of-bounded-functions-is-reflexive-if-the-domain-is-finite).

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. For $x \in X$ we define $\delta_x : C_b(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{K}, \ f \mapsto f(x)$. Prove that the space $C_b(X)$ is reflexive iff $X$ is finite.

If $X$ is infinite, then there is an injective mapping $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow X, \ n \mapsto x_n$, such that

$T: l^1 \rightarrow C_b(X)', \ \ (\alpha_n)_n \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_n \delta_{x_n}$.

I want to prove that $T$ is a well-defined isometric homomorphism. 
I always have a problem with this kind of questions. First of all how do I prove that $T$ is well-defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\|\mu\|$ denote the total variation norm of $\mu$.

$T$ is well defined because $\|\sum \alpha_n \delta_{x_n}\| \leq \sum |\alpha_n|=\|(\alpha_n)\|$ since $\|\delta_{x_n}\|=1$. [In any Banach space $\sum \|y_n|| <\infty$ implies that the series $\sum y_n$ converges].

Also $\|\sum \alpha_n \delta_{x_n}\|\geq \sum_k | (\sum_n\alpha_n \delta_{x_n}) (E_k)|$ where $E_k=\{x_k\}$  so  $\|T(\alpha_n)\|=\sum |\alpha _n|=\|(\alpha_n)\|$ and $T$ is an isometry.

The fact that $\ell^{1}$ is isometrically isomorphic to a subspace of $C_b(X)$ implies that $C_b(X)$ is not reflexive. Hence $C_b(X)$ is not reflexive whenever $X$ is an infinite set. If $X$ is finite it is clear that $C_b(X)$ is reflexive.

Comment: please show me how to prove that $T$ is a homomorphism

Comment: To answer the question in the title you only need the fact that $T$ is a linear isometry. In what sense do you want to show that $T$ is a homomorphism? Are you consideing $\ell^{1}$ as an algebra under convolution? @MathStudent

Comment: My bad. In a metric space a homomorphism is just a linear map. I take my question back. Sorry. And thank you

Answer (score 1):

**$T$ is well-defined**:

From the description 
$(\alpha_n)_n \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_n \delta_{x_n}$
it is not immediately clear that $T$ is actually a function from $\ell^1$ to $C_b(X)'$.
Thus, for $T$ being well-defined you have to show that
$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_n \delta_{x_n}\in C_b(X)'$ for all $(\alpha_n)_n\in\ell^1$.