# Is B(H) a Hilbert space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

If H is a Hilbert space, Is B(H) under the operator norm a Hilbert space?
If not, is there exists any norm on B(H) that makes it a Hilbert space?

Comment: No, $B(H)$ is not a Hilbert space, but this is a $C^*$ algebra. To prove that it is not a Hilbert space just try to construct a counterexample to the parallelogram identity. Some subspaces of $B(H)$ do form a Hilbert Space. Check out Trace Class operators.

Comment: @leshik Do you want the trace class operators or the Hilbert-Schmidt operators?

Comment: @ Andreas Blass: Certainly, Hilbert- Schmidt, thanks :)

Comment: @leshik and @ A Blass - Thanks. So the subspace of B(H) consisting of Hilbert Schmidt operators on H become a Hilbert space. What will be the inner product in this case?

Comment: Have a look at [Hilbert- Schmidt operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert–Schmidt_operator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call something a Hilbert space means that it is equipped with a complete *inner product*, not just a norm. A complete normed vector space is called a *Banach space*, and indeed $B(H)$ with the operator norm is a Banach space. Indeed, it has some additional structure (multiplication given by composition, and an involution given by taking adjoints) which makes it a [C*-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra).

Of course, you can still ask whether there exists an inner product on $B(H)$ which makes it a Hilbert space, and this depends on $H$:

If $H$ is finite-dimensional, then choosing a basis identifies it with $\mathbb{C}^n$ for $n=\dim H$, and $B(H)$ is identified with the space of $n\times n$ matrices, which is a Hilbert space.

If $H$ is infinite-dimensional, then $B(H)$ is not a Hilbert space: see  [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112844/c-algebra-which-is-also-a-hilbert-space) for some reasons why.

Comment: @ Brad. Thanks for your informative answer. What is the norm and inner product in M_n?

Comment: We can equip $M_n$ with an inner product by declaring that the matrices $E_{ij}$, which have all entries $0$ except for a $1$ in the $(i,j)^{\mathrm{th}}$ position, form an orthonormal basis. That is, $\langle A,B\rangle = \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}\bar b_{ij}$. The norm is then given by $|A| = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2}$.

Comment: Sorry for the criticism, but the finite-dimensional identification you provide is not particularly useful: you end up with a different norm, unless $\dim(H) = 1$ holds. The OP asks specifically if $B(H)$ is a Hilbert space *under the operator norm*. For this question, the answer is simply no unless $\dim(H) = 1$ holds, as shown in the [other question you already mentioned](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/112844/246783). For $\dim(H) = \infty$ we might just be able to find a Hilbert space that is *algebraically* (though not isometrically) isomorphic to $B(H)$, but this is not the question.

Comment: Oh wait, your answer *does* indeed answer the second question, so my criticism is not entirely justified. Sorry! :-) Still I'm not entirely convinced that it's impossible to find a Hilbert space norm on $B(H)$ if $H$ is infinite-dimensional. Unfortunately, the Hilbert–Schmidt norm will not work since it is infinite for some operators.

Answer (score 6):

For your first question: we have that $B(H)$ is a Hilbert space if and only if $\dim(H) \leq 1$ holds.

- If $\dim(H) \leq 1$ holds, then it is clear that $B(H)$ is a Hilbert space.
- If $\dim(H) > 1$ holds, then we may choose $x,y\in H$ with $\lVert x \rVert = \lVert y \rVert = 1$ and $\langle x, y\rangle = 0$. Let $P : z \mapsto \langle z,x\rangle \cdot x$ and $Q : z \mapsto \langle z,y\rangle\cdot y$ denote the orthogonal projections onto $\text{span}(x)$ and $\text{span}(y)$, respectively, then we have
  $$ \lVert P + Q \rVert^2 + \lVert P - Q \rVert^2 \: = \: 1 + 1 \: = \: 2, $$
  but also
  $$ 2\Big(\lVert P \rVert^2 + \lVert Q\rVert^2\Big) \: = \: 2\cdot (1 + 1) \: = \: 4. $$
  We see that $B(H)$ does not satisfy the [parallelogram rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law), so it cannot be a Hilbert space.

As for your second question, Brad already pointed out a different norm on $B(H)$ that turns it into a Hilbert space in case $H$ is finite-dimensional. This norm can be generalised to infinite dimensions, where it is known as the [Hilbert–Schmidt norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator), and one can prove that this does indeed satisfy the parallelogram rule. However, unfortunately not all elements of $B(H)$ have finite Hilbert–Schmidt norm, unless $H$ is finite-dimensional. Thus, you get a proper subspace $\mathcal{HS}(H) \subsetneq B(H)$ consisting of *Hilbert–Schmidt operators* (that is, operators with finite Hilbert–Schmidt norm). The inner product can be given by $\langle A, B\rangle = \text{tr}(B^*A)$, where you have to prove first that the product of two Hilbert–Schmidt operators is a trace class operator.

Edit: even in the infinite-dimensional case there exists a different norm $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_2$ that turns $B(H)$ into a Hilbert space, as by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1599903/246783). However, this does not provide us with an explicit representation of $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_2$, and there is no guarantee that it should be a Banach algebra norm. [I posted a follow-up question about this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1705879/246783).

For more on Hilbert–Schmidt operators I know the following references (though there may be others):

- John B. Conway, *A Course in Functional Analysis*, exercises IX.2.19 and IX.2.20.
- Gerard J. Murphy, *$C^*$-algebras and operator theory*, section 2.4. (Excellent book!)