# Submultiplicative Hilbert space norm on $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and let $B(H)$ denote the space of bounded linear operators $H \to H$ equipped with operator norm:
$$ \lVert T \rVert = \sup\big\{ \lVert Tx \rVert \: : \: \lVert x \rVert \leq 1\big\}. $$
[One easily shows](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1703869/246783) that $B(H)$ is not a Hilbert space whenever $\dim(H) > 1$ holds, for it does not satisfy the [parallelogram rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1703869/246783). Furthermore, [an abstract argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1599903/246783) shows that there exists a Hilbert space norm $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_2$ on $B(H)$, but it does not provide us with a very concrete description of such a norm. In the finite-dimensional case one might take the [Hilbert–Schmidt norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm): this turns $B(H)$ into a Hilbert space and it is known to be submultiplicative. However, in the infinite-dimensional case this does not work, for now the space of Hilbert–Schmidt operators is a proper subspace of $B(H)$. This leads me to the following question:

> **Question.** *Is there a submultiplicative Hilbert space norm on $B(H)$ if $H$ is infinite-dimensional, either by abstract reasoning or by concrete example? For the moment I do not care whether this new norm is equivalent to the operator norm.*

This is a strengthening of the question [Is B(H) a Hilbert space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/441404/246783) which did not ask for submultiplicativity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **no**: such a norm **does not exist**. First I'll give a short-ish proof; after that I will spell out some of the details for the benefit of those who do not know these already.

> **Assumption.** All spaces (vector spaces, algebras, etc.) under consideration are complex.

We prove something slightly stronger.

> **Theorem.** *Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, and let $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert$ be a norm on $B(H)$ such that for each $a\in B(H)$ the left and right multiplication operators $L_a : b\mapsto ab$, $R_a : b\mapsto ba$ are continuous. Then $B(H)$ is not reflexive with respect to $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert$. In particular, $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert$ cannot be a Hilbert space norm.*
>
> *Proof.* If $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert$ is not complete, then clearly $B(H)$ is not reflexive with respect to this norm. So we assume for the remainder of this proof that $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert$ is complete. Now there exists an equivalent norm $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_{\text{Ban}}$ on $B(H)$ turning $B(H)$ into a unital Banach algebra (in other words, we have $\lVert ab\rVert_{\text{Ban}} \leq \lVert a\rVert_{\text{Ban}} \cdot \lVert b\rVert_{\text{Ban}}$ for all $a,b\in B(H)$, and $\lVert \text{id} \rVert_{\text{Ban}} = 1$).
>
> Now choose some orthonormal basis $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $H$, and let $A \subseteq B(H)$ be the subalgebra of diagonal operators with respect to this basis. Then $A$ is equal to its own commutator, and therefore it is $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_{\text{Ban}}$-closed. This means that $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_{\text{Ban}}$ turns $A$ into a Banach algebra. But $A$ is algebra-isomorphic to $\ell^\infty(I)$, which is unital, commutative and semisimple, so we know that all Banach algebra norms on $A$ are equivalent. In other words, the algebra isomorphism $A \cong \ell^\infty(I)$ is also an isomorphism of Banach spaces¹ $(A,\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_{\text{Ban}})\cong(\ell^\infty(I),\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_\infty)$. Since $I$ is infinite, we know that $(\ell^\infty(I),\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_\infty)$ is not reflexive, so it follows that $(A,\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_{\text{Ban}})$ is not reflexive either. Since $A$ is closed in $(B(H),\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_{\text{Ban}})$, it follows that $(B(H),\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_{\text{Ban}})$ also fails to be reflexive.
>
> Finally, since the norms $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert$ and $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_{\text{Ban}}$ are equivalent, it follows that $B(H)$ is not reflexive with respect to $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert$.$\quad\blacksquare$

¹: By *isomorphism of Banach spaces* we mean an invertible bounded linear operator, not necessarily isometric. Strictly speaking, such a map is not an isomorphism of Banach spaces, since the norm is part of the Banach space structure. A better term would be *isomorphism of Banachable spaces*. See also [this discussion on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80567/what-is-an-isomorphism-of-banach-spaces).

$$ {} $$

---

$$ {} $$

We proceed to fill in some of the details (references given below).

$$ {} $$

> **Fact 1.** *A reflexive normed space must be complete*.
>
> *Proof.* [Dual spaces are complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026961/proof-of-dual-normed-vector-space-is-complete).
>
> See also: [Rynne&Youngson] Definition 5.38, or [Conway] Definition III.11.2.$\quad\Box$

$$ {} $$

> **Fact 2.** *Existence of the equivalent Banach algebra norm $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_{\text{Ban}}$.*
>
> *Proof.* See any one of the following sources:
>
> - [Conway] Exercise VII.1.1;
> - [Kaniuth] Proposition 1.1.1;
> - [Rudin] Theorem 10.2.$\hspace{10cm}\Box$

$$ {} $$

> **Fact 3.** *$A$ is equal to its own commutator.*
>
> *Proof.* Since $A$ is commutative, we have $A \subseteq A'$. Now let $b\in A'$ be given. We show that $b$ must be diagonal with respect to $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$. To that end, choose some $i_0 \in I$ and let $a\in A$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $v_{i_0}$ (this is the diagonal operator given by $v_{i_0} \mapsto v_{i_0}$ and $v_j \mapsto 0$ for all $j \neq i_0$). Then we have $bv_{i_0} = bav_{i_0} = abv_{i_0}$, hence $bv_{i_0} \in \text{im}(a) = \text{span}(v_{i_0})$. We see that every $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $b$, so indeed $b$ is diagonal with respect to $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$.$\quad\Box$

$$ {} $$

> **Fact 4.** *A commutator in a Banach algebra is closed.*
>
> *Proof.* Let $X$ be a Banach algebra and $S \subseteq X$ a subset. Then we have
>   $$ S' = \bigcap_{s\in S} \: \ker(L_s - R_s), $$
>   which is closed since it is an intersection of closed sets. (Here $L_s : r \mapsto sr$ and $R_s : r \mapsto rs$ denote the left and right multiplication operators. We have $L_s,R_s \in B(X)$, so that $\ker(L_s - R_s)$ is closed.)$\quad\Box$

$$ {} $$

> **Fact 5.** *For any index set $I$, the algebra $\ell^\infty(I)$ is semisimple.*
>
> *Proof.* It admits a $C^*$-algebra structure, and commutative $C^*$-algebras are semisimple. (Recall that a commutative Banach algebra $X$ is semisimple if and only if the Gelfand representation $X\to C_0(\Omega(X))$ is injective.)$\quad\Box$

$$ {} $$

> **Fact 6.** *In a unital, commutative and semisimple algebra, all Banach algebra norms are equivalent.*
>
> *Proof.* See any one of the following sources:
>
> - [Conway] Exercise VII.8.15;
> - [Kaniuth] Corollary 2.1.11;
> - [Pedersen] Exercise 4.2.13;
> - [Rudin] Corollary 11.10.$\hspace{10cm}\Box$

$$ {} $$

> **Fact 7.** *A closed subspace of a reflexive Banach space is again reflexive.*
>
> *Proof.* See any one of the following sources:
>
> - [Conway] Exercise III.11.4;
> - [Pedersen] Exercise 2.4.8;
> - [Rudin] Exercise 4.1(d);
> - [Rynne&Youngson] Theorem 5.44.$\hspace{8cm}\Box$

$$ {} $$

> **Fact 8.** *If $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_1$ and $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_2$ are equivalent norms on a vector space $X$, then $(X,\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_1)$ is reflexive if and only if $(X,\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_2)$ is reflexive. Consequently, if $T : X \to Y$ is an invertible bounded linear operator on normed spaces $X,Y$, then $X$ is reflexive if and only if $Y$ is reflexive.*
>
> *Proof.* Since $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_1$ and $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_2$ induce the same topology, the dual spaces $(X,\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_1)^*$ and $(X,\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_1)^*$ are not only isomorphic, but actually *the same* vector space. It is easily seen that the corresponding dual norms are equivalent. Taking this one step further, it is clear that the natural maps $J_1 : (X,\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_1) \to (X,\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_1)^{**}$ and $J_2 : (X,\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_2) \to (X,\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_2)^{**}$ are equal. Therefore $J_1$ is surjective if and only if $J_2$ is surjective.
>
> Now let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces and let $T : X \to Y$ be an invertible bounded linear operator. We let $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_1$ denote the original norm on $X$ and $\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_2$ the norm on $X$ obtained from $Y$ via $T$, so that $T$ is an isometric isomorphism $(X,\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_2)\cong Y$. Clearly $(X,\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_2)$ is reflexive if and only if $Y$ is reflexive, since they are *isometrically* isomorphic (and thus, in every sense, the same Banach space). Now it follows from the above that $(X,\lVert\:\cdot\:\rVert_1)$ is reflexive if and only if $Y$ is reflexive.
>
> For an alternative proof, see [Rynne&Youngson] Corollary 5.56.$\quad\Box$

$$ {} $$

> **Fact 9.** *For any infinite set $I$, the space $\ell^\infty(I)$ is irreflexive.*
>
> *Proof.* Choose some countably infinite subset $J \subseteq I$, then $\ell^\infty(J)$ is easily seen to be a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty(I)$ that is isometrically isomorphic to the sequence space $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$. The latter is known to be irreflexive, so we see that $\ell^\infty(J)$, and therefore $\ell^\infty(I)$, are irreflexive as well (using Fact 7).$\quad\Box$

$$ {} $$

---

$$ {} $$

**References:**

[Conway]: John B. Conway, *A Course in Functional Analysis* (1985), Springer Graduate Texts in Mathematics 96.

[Kaniuth]: Eberhard Kaniuth, *A Course in Commutative Banach Algebras* (2009), Springer Graduate Texts in Mathematics 246.

[Pedersen]: Gerd K. Pedersen, *Analysis Now*, Revised Printing (1995), Springer Graduate Texts in Mathematics 118.

[Rudin]: Walter Rudin, *Functional Analysis*, Second Edition (1991), McGraw–Hill.

[Rynne&Youngson]: Bryan P. Rynne & Martin A. Youngson, *Linear Functional Analysis*, Second Edition (2008), Springer Undergraduate Mathematics Series.