# Hilbert space structure on $C^{*}$ algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

What is  an example of  an infinite dimensional    $C^{*}$ algebra with a Hilbert space  structure (not merely pre-hilbert structure)   such that the orthogonal complement of  each closed left ideal is again a closed left ideal?

Comment: You mean a C*-algebra who's norm is given by a scalar product?

Comment: Hopefully you don't mean that, because such a thing doesn't exist with dimension greater than 1.  What do you mean exactly Ali?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Interesting. Please could you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer:http://math.stackexchange.com/q/112844

Comment: @JonasMeyer Sorry for my delay. No but I mean a Hilbert space structure whose topology coincide to the original topology of C^*  algebra.

Comment: @Freeze_S  sorry for my delay. Please read the above comment. My motivation is the finite dimensional algebras.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: do you have an example of an infinite-dimensional $C^*$-algebra which is isomorphic to a Hilbert space as topological vector space?

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk  No I don't have. What about if we try with that  C* algebra generated by diagonal operators on H?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I have just learned from here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112844/c-algebra-which-is-also-a-hilbert-space?rq=1 that every infinite dimensional C*-algebra is a strict subset of its second dual. (See the second answer and discussion there). It shows that infinite dimensional $C^*$-algebras cannot have the topology of a Hilbert space.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk  What about if we intersect the later algebra with finite rank or trace class operators?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: But finite-rank operators and trace-class operators are not closed in $B(H).$ If you take all diagonal operators, it is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^\infty,$ which is not reflexive. Hence cannot have the topology of a Hilbert space.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk thank you for the link.