# Infinite dimensional C*-algebra contains infinite dimensional commutitive subalgebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

I was reading a paper which mentioned without proof that every infinite-dimensional $C$* algebra has an infinite-dimensional commutative $C$* subalgebra.

Thinking about it for 10 minutes, I didn't see an immediately proof. It is sufficient to construct an element with infinite spectrum, but I don't see how to construct such an element.

Moreover, if one takes infinitely many noncommuting infinite and co-infinite projections on a Hilbert space, and takes the $C$* algebra generated by those projections, I don't see a reason why this contains an infinite-dimensional commutative $C$* subalgebra. (Clearly this is not a proven counterexample.)

Is there an easy proof of this fact?

Comment: Maybe http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/the-spectrum-of-normal-operators-in-c-algebras will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marten, this is true by an observation due to Kaplansky, I believe, which asserts that an infinite-dimensional C*-algebra contains a self-adjoint element with infinite spectrum. See Ex. 4.6.12 in

> R. V. Kadison and J. R. Ringrose, *Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras*, Vol. I, Elementary Theory, Pure and Applied Math., Vol. 100 Academic Press, New York (1983).

Now, apply the spectral theorem to such an element $x$. Using continuous functional calculus, you will get that $C^*(x)=C_0(\sigma(x))$, which is infinite-dimensional as $\sigma(x)$ is an infinite compact set.